# Como criar mais de uma classe em C#

Tags: c#

```
public class Veiculo
{
    public int id;
    public int chassis;
    public int placa;
    public int numeroMotor;
    public int renavan;
    public DateTime ano;
    public string modelo;
    public bool situacao;
    public string cor;
    public string cidadeDeRegistro;
    public string proprietario;
    public string nome;

}

// Como faço para criar outras classe como "Montadora" e "Modelos"??
```

Comment: Fala Leidervan, bem vindo ao site. Para ter mais chances de obter uma resposta, sugiro editar sua pergunta e adicionar algumas informações. Por exemplo: O que você já tentou? Deu algum erro? Qual erro e em qual linha? Qual é a dúvida concreta e pontual? Sei que não é o caso, mas do jeito que está, fica parecendo que quer que façamos um trabalho ou dever para você, e o foco do site é apenas em perguntas e respostas bem definidas. Um abraço e boa sorte!